# Writing own memmem for Windows

Tags: c

I notcied that `memmem` is not available in MSVC for Windows, so I tried to write something for it. I have the following code:

```
void *memmem(const void *haystack_start, size_t haystack_len, const void *needle_start, size_t needle_len)
{
    const unsigned char *haystack = (const unsigned char *)haystack_start;
    const unsigned char *needle = (const unsigned char *)needle_start;
    const unsigned char *h = NULL;
    const unsigned char *n = NULL;
    size_t x = needle_len;

    /* The first occurrence of the empty string is deemed to occur at
    the beginning of the string.  */
    if (needle_len == 0) {
        return (void *)haystack_start;
    }

    /* Sanity check, otherwise the loop might search through the whole
        memory.  */
    if (haystack_len < needle_len) {
        return NULL;
    }

    for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {
        x = needle_len;
        n = needle;
        h = haystack;

        if (haystack_len < needle_len)
            break;

        if ((*haystack != *needle) || (*haystack + needle_len != *needle + needle_len))
            continue;

        for (; x; h++, n++) {
            x--;

            if (*h != *n)
                break;

            if (x == 0)
                return (void *)haystack;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

But, I do not think it works correctly. If I try something like this:

```
static const char haystack[24] = {
    0x4e, 0x65, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x67, 0x6f,
    0x6e, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x20, 0x67, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65,
    0x20, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x75, 0x70, 0x2c,
};

static const char needle[8] = {
    0x20, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x75, 0x70, 0x2c
};

char *res = memmem(haystack, sizeof(haystack), needle, sizeof(needle));
printf("%s", res);
```

The result is null. Any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: You need to debug this by using your debugger. If you are not willing to invest some time in learning how to use your debugger, you can still add `printf`s at strategic points of your program in order to check what's going on.

Comment: In `(*haystack != *needle) || (*haystack + needle_len != *needle + needle_len`), the conditions are equivalent. Did you forget some parentheses? (Indexing is much easier to get right than pointer arithmetic.)

Comment: "*haystack + needle_len" I think you meant to add the pointer before you dereference them. This will fetch the values then add the lengths to the retrieved values. Not that this should make a difference, though, but won't check the end of the strings. (Although if you did want to check the last char, that would be needle_len - 1.)

Comment: Why do you check if `*haystack` is true in a loop. Is haystack a null delimetered string?

Comment: I updated the as per some of the comments. But, it still doesn't seem to work for my above provided example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

```
void *memmem(const void *haystack, size_t haystack_len, 
    const void * const needle, const size_t needle_len)
{
    if (haystack == NULL) return NULL; // or assert(haystack != NULL);
    if (haystack_len == 0) return NULL;
    if (needle == NULL) return NULL; // or assert(needle != NULL);
    if (needle_len == 0) return NULL;
    
    for (const char *h = haystack;
            haystack_len >= needle_len;
            ++h, --haystack_len) {
        if (!memcmp(h, needle, needle_len)) {
            return h;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Until haystack_len is greater or equal to needle_len, you should memory compare needle with current position in haystack. If it's true, return haystack.

1. There is no need to explicitly cast a `const void *` pointer `const unsigned char *haystack = (const unsigned char *)haystack_start;` is just `const unsigned char *haystack = haystack_start;`
2. As said in comments by @molbdnilo `(*haystack != *needle) || (*haystack + needle_len != *needle + needle_len))`  is just the same think. It becomes obvious, once you use `[]` operator rather then `*`: `haystack[0] != needle[0] || haystack[0] + needle_len != needle[0] + needle_len`. Even if you meant `... != needle[needle_len]` this is out-of-bound access of needle.
3. The for is just strange:

```
for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {
      if (haystack_len < needle_len)
            break;
```

Why not:

```
for (; *haystack && haystack_len < needle_len; haystack_len--, haystack++)
```

?

And the expression `*haystack`  is just invalid, you are not checking null-terminated string like in case of `strstr`. haystack points to any bytes in memory and may have zero as values. The `haystack_len` keeps the length of haystack.

4. You can use memcmp to compare memory, no need to write that part yourself.

Comment: Wow this seems really elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: Replace `memcmp` with a local loop to optimize things, as in the original code. Further, it is a good answer.

Comment: Replace `assert` with `return(NULL);` so as not to break the code (assert may abort the program).

Comment: Replace `return (void*)haystack;` with `return(NULL);`, assuming an empty needle implies the needle is not in the haystack (see man page at https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmem)

Comment: Why is local loop more optimized then memcmp? memcmp may use architecture specific instructions and do it way faster. So I chose memcmp, out of elegancy and speed. For short needles the branch overhead will be definitely big, but maybe for big needles and low entropy haystacks... Probably some hybrid like `if (h[0] == needle[0] && (needle_len > 1 ? !memcmp(&h[1], &needle[1], needle_len - 1) : 1))` would be faster in certain cases. But that depends really on data. As for the rest - return NULL and empty needle case - I agree 100%

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is pretty good, but there are easy optimizations that can be made.  For example, windows does provide a memchr function, and it is probably written in assembly language and is much more efficient than manually looping one character at a time from C and calling memcmp at every character.  I didn't perform any benchmarks, but almost certainly this is not ideal.

Here's a solution the makes use of this optimization.  We do the primary search with memchr to find the first byte of the needle, then do a memcmp to check the rest.  Since there are 256 possible values for a byte, on average this will reduce the number of calls to memcmp by a factor of 255.

```
void *os_memmem(const void *src,int srclen,const void *trg,int trglen)
{
unsigned char *csrc = (unsigned char *)src;
unsigned char *ctrg = (unsigned char *)trg;
unsigned char *tptr,*cptr;
int searchlen,ndx=0;

    /* add some initial error checking if you want */

    while (ndx<=srclen) {
        cptr = &csrc[ndx];
        if ((searchlen = srclen-ndx-trglen+1) <= 0) {
            return NULL;
        } /* if */
        if ((tptr = memchr(cptr,*ctrg,searchlen)) == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        } /* if */
        if (memcmp(tptr,ctrg,trglen) == 0) {
            return tptr;
        } /* if */
        ndx += tptr-cptr+1;
    } /* while */
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following statements are the same

```
char needle[] = "a test";
char needle[7] = { 'a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '\0' };
```

Your `haystack` does not have a `'\0'` at the same place as `needle`.

Try with

```
// needle is NOT a string
char needle[6] = "a test"; // needle is NOT a string
```

Comment: Yes, noticed it now. Thanks. Check updated question. I changed using new data. Still null for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (; *haystack && haystack_len--; haystack++) {
```

Here you're decrementing haystack_len at the start of the loop. This means that when you reach your match haystack_len = 7 but needle_len = 8. Therefore you fail the  `f (haystack_len < needle_len)` check and `continue`. As Kamil notes in the comments you probably don't want a nul check on haystack either. So I'd suggest

```
for (; haystack_len > 0; ++haystack, --haystack_len) {
```