# memmem() in Mingw-w64 gcc

Tags: c, gcc, mingw-w64

I'm trying to build a C program with Windows gcc using Mingw-w64 installation (gcc.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0).

I get *undefined reference to `memmem'* error. Isn't memmem() a standard glibc function that should be available in all gcc versions?

Comment: with what command line(s)?

Comment: C:/My/Programs/Mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -g C:\My\Code\Tests\GCCWinCTest\main.c -o C:\My\Code\Tests\GCCWinCTest\main.exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard C library in mingW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394512/standard-c-library-in-mingw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394512/standard-c-library-in-mingw) explains

> "MinGW does not build against glibc, it builds against msvcrt. As
> such, it uses libmsvcrtXX.a instead." "gcc and glibc are two separate
> products."

So, yep, no memmem on Windows and [here's the implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988769/writing-own-memmem-for-windows)

Comment: thanks for the answer. This is pretty annoying!